# when try to push value on variable push undefined not value

Tags: javascript, ajax, push

I am try to push value in a variable using javascript `push()`.
It's three values.

1. Latitude
2. Longitude
3. Region

Latitude and longitude push successfully; region is not pushed - it's Undefined.

I know this is a variable definition problem but also even though I define this variable globally, I still get this problem.

This is my code:-

```
var get_all = new Array;
var result_lat = new Array;
var result_lng = new Array;
var activity_2= "Rajkot,Jamnagar,Surat";
var array_rg_name = activity_2.split(',');
            var cn = "IN";
for (var i=0; i<array_rg_name.length; i++ ){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://services.gisgraphy.com//geocoding/geocode?address="+array_rg_name[i]+"&country="+cn+"&format=json",
      async: false,
      dataType:'jsonp',
      success: function(data){        
            lat = data.result[0].lat;
            result_lat.push(lat);
            lng = data.result[0].lng;
            result_lng.push(lng);
          get_all.push('Latitude: '+lat,'Longitude: '+lng,'Region: '+ array_rg_name[i]);
          }
            });
        }
$('button').click(function(){
    alert(result_lat);
 alert(result_lng);
 alert(get_all);
})
```

There is a jsfiddle link :- http://jsfiddle.net/Tr6sm/2/

Any suggestions?

Comment: The ajax calls are asynchronous, so by the time your callback runs the loop has finished and the `i` variable is equal to `array_rg_name.length` - which means at that point `array_rg_name[i]` _is_ undefined. (The async nature of the ajax also explains why you get blank alerts if you press the button immediately before the Ajax responses come in.)

Comment: @nnnnnn but the async is set to false. How can this behavior happen ?

Comment: my bad, clearly written in the documentation, jsonp requests are always asynchronous.

Comment: @nnnnnn just read it just after posting the comment. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THis should work [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tr6sm/8/)

Notice I am defining rg as a part of ajax call rg:array_rg_name[i] ... and using this.rg later...

```
var get_all = new Array;
var result_lat = new Array;
var result_lng = new Array;
var activity_2= "Rajkot,Jamnagar,Surat";
var array_rg_name = activity_2.split(',');
            var cn = "IN";
for (var i=0; i<array_rg_name.length; i++ ){

            $.ajax({
                rg: array_rg_name[i],
                url: "http://services.gisgraphy.com//geocoding/geocode?address="+array_rg_name[i]+"&country="+cn+"&format=json",
                async: false,
                dataType:'jsonp',
                success: function(data){        
                     lat = data.result[0].lat;
                     result_lat.push(lat);
                     lng = data.result[0].lng;
                     result_lng.push(lng);
                     get_all.push('Latitude: '+lat,'Longitude: '+lng,'Region: '+ this.rg);
                 }
            });
}
$('button').click(function(){
    alert(result_lat);
 alert(result_lng);
 alert(get_all);
})
```

Comment: +1. Nice. I didn't previously realise that the context within the callback would be set to the options object. (Or that you can set it to something else by specifying the `context` option.)